# Can't retrieve value from object in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm currently working in Laravel4.

I'm trying to loop through an array containing a list of company names to populate a dropdown menu, and it just doesn't work. I either get an error about array to string conversion failing or object to string conversion failing. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Here is the view:

```
            <div>
                Carehome type:
        <select name='carehome_type'>
            @foreach($companies as $company)
                <option value="{{$company}}" >{{$company}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>  
    </div>
```

And here is the controller:

```
public function getCreate(){
        $view = View::make('account.create');
        $companies = DB::table('homes')->select('Company')->distinct()->get(array());

        return $view->with('companies', $companies);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result set is an array of objects and in each iteration you have an object at your disposal.

That's why you get an object to string conversion when trying`{{$company}}`.

You have to specify which property of the object you want. Try this:

```
@foreach($companies as $company)

  <option value="{{$company->Company}}" >{{$company->Company}}</option>

@endforeach
```

where **Company** corresponds to the field you selected with `select('Company')`

Comment: thanks that works perfectly! I had tried but with company instead of Company